# Henry's Law with varying temperature

Tags: gas-laws, temperature

I am [trying to determine](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/2223/641) what the derived partial pressure would be for CO2 in the global atmosphere from historical inconstant temperatures and CO2 concentrations of the global atmosphere:

[image]

Is it possible to do this?  If so, how?

Comment: An expression for partial pressure, or some sort of useful single value? Did you mean partial pressure of CO2 or something else?

Comment: @rch Thank you for looking rch!  I don't think I was concentrating when I wrote that.  I'll edit...

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is no.

The long answer is:

Henry's law works for small concentrations of ideal mixtures at equilibrium. [Henry's Law constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry's_law) varies with temperature according to the [Van't Hoff equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_%27t_Hoff_equation):

$$
k(T)=k(T^{\circ})exp\left[-C\left(\frac{1}{T}-\frac{1}{T\circ}\right)\right]
$$

Here $C$ is a constant related to the enthalpy of solvation for each gas, and $^{\circ}$ represents the standard state, T = 298 K and 1 atm.

Using standard state data, you could get an estimate of the partial pressure at a given temperature. However, two key assumptions that are implicit to Henry's law and the Van't Hoff equation do not hold for global atmospheric gas composition:

1. The atmosphere and the oceans are not at equilibrium (not even close when you consider atmospheric layers and convection)
2. $\ce{CO2}$ in seawater is not an ideal mixture (very non-ideal since $\ce{CO2}$ reacts with water).

This is one of the many reasons that climate modeling is difficult - the oceans act as huge carbon sinks with a very complex and not-very-stable relationship between dissolved $\ce{CO2}$ content, temperature, composition of rock on the sea floor, convection currents in the atmosphere and the ocean, amount of shellfish (no kidding), and probably lots of other factors (I'm not a climate expert).

The net result is that while Henry's law can get you a quick idea of how much $\ce{CO2}$ could be dissolved at a given temperature under pseudo-equilibrium conditions (or what the corresponding partial pressure would be for a given concentration in water), it isn't enough to get you anywhere close to a good prediction of what the global atmospheric composition will be, particularly for $\ce{CO2}$ (due to its reactivity with water and incorporation into biomass).

Now, if you really just want to convert $\ce{CO2}$ concentration in ppm to a partial pressure, you can do that.

$\ce{CO2}$ in air is *close enough* to ideal that we can use the ideal gas law. For an ideal gas, the partial pressure is the same as whatever the pressure *would* be if it were in a container by itself:

$$
P_1 = \frac{n_1RT}{V}
$$

You can find V for a given mass of air, find the mass of $\ce{CO2}$ from the concentration, then convert to moles and plug it into the above.

Answer (score 1):

You currently have numbers in ppm (of ${CO_2}$); ppm values for gas tend to be equivalent to ${\mu mol/mol}$ units. Can't you just use that, the the definition of partial pressure, and the atmospheric pressure and be set (though it varies by altitude and a little over time too)? [Some forum](http://forum.onlineconversion.com/showthread.php?t=11529) has a similar homework-level question. Not sure if I'm missing something with that.

I take it you wanted to use Henry's Law to relate concentration to partial pressure. typically that's used in the realm of vapor-liquid systems; not sure how it fares in a mixture of many gases that I'd qualify the atmosphere as. See things to note: [(Chemwiki)](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Physical_Chemistry/Physical_Properties_of_Matter/Solutions_and_Mixtures/Ideal_Solutions/Dissolving_Gases_In_Liquids%2C_Henry's_Law)

Looking at a (pretty crude IMHO) pressure vs altitude graph of the atmosphere [(Wikipedia: Atmospheric pressure)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_pressure): you can see the pressure even within the troposphere ranges from ~12kPa all the way to ~100kPa (sea level: ~101 kPa). The troposphere has 80% of the atmosphere's mass and you want the whole atmosphere anyways, so just take 101kPa as atmospheric pressure? I also assume atmosphere's mass is constant over the span of 400 million years - no clue on whether I can neglect losses and gains from weather, the biosphere, and space over this time span. Then you will have a bunch of carbon dioxide partial pressures over time.

[image: stdatm]

On short-term constancy of the atmosphere's mass, see [SE.Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/65923/is-the-total-mass-of-earths-atmosphere-essentially-constant-in-time). The mean even changes by season. It's comparatively small comparing 1.5E+15 kg to the total of 5.15E+18 kg.